# Why I cant write dataframe in DB?

Tags: database, python-2.7, pandas

I have 32 gb RAM and I use jupyter and pandas. My dataframe isn't very big, but when I want to write it in Arctic data base I have "MemoryError":

```
df_q.shape
(157293660, 10)
def memory(df):
    mem = df.memory_usage(index=True).sum() / (1024 ** 3)
    print(mem)
memory(df_q)
12.8912200034
```

And I want to write it:

```
from arctic import Arctic
import arctic as arc
store = Arctic('.....')
lib = store['myLib']
lib.write('quotes', df_q)
```

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 memory(df_q)
>   ----> 2 lib.write('quotes', df_q)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arctic/decorators.pyc in
>   f_retry(*args, **kwargs)
>        48             while True:
>        49                 try:
>   ---> 50                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
>        51                 except (DuplicateKeyError, ServerSelectionTimeoutError) as e:
>        52                     # Re-raise errors that won't go away.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arctic/store/version_store.pyc
>   in write(self, symbol, data, metadata, prune_previous_version,
>   **kwargs)
>       561 
>       562         handler = self._write_handler(version, symbol, data, **kwargs)
>   --> 563         mongo_retry(handler.write)(self._arctic_lib, version, symbol, data, previous_version, **kwargs)
>       564 
>       565         # Insert the new version into the version DB
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arctic/decorators.pyc in
>   f_retry(*args, **kwargs)
>        48             while True:
>        49                 try:
>   ---> 50                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
>        51                 except (DuplicateKeyError, ServerSelectionTimeoutError) as e:
>        52                     # Re-raise errors that won't go away.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arctic/store/_pandas_ndarray_store.pyc
>   in write(self, arctic_lib, version, symbol, item, previous_version)
>       301     def write(self, arctic_lib, version, symbol, item, previous_version):
>       302         item, md = self.to_records(item)
>   --> 303         super(PandasDataFrameStore, self).write(arctic_lib, version, symbol, item, previous_version, dtype=md)
>       304 
>       305     def append(self, arctic_lib, version, symbol, item, previous_version):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arctic/store/_ndarray_store.pyc
>   in write(self, arctic_lib, version, symbol, item, previous_version,
>   dtype)
>       385         version['type'] = self.TYPE
>       386         version['up_to'] = len(item)
>   --> 387         version['sha'] = self.checksum(item)
>       388 
>       389         if previous_version:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arctic/store/_ndarray_store.pyc
>   in checksum(self, item)
>       370     def checksum(self, item):
>       371         sha = hashlib.sha1()
>   --> 372         sha.update(item.tostring())
>       373         return Binary(sha.digest())
>       374
>
> MemoryError:

WTF ?
If I use df_q.to_csv() I will wait for years....

Comment: Did you try to write your DF in [chunks](https://github.com/manahl/arctic/blob/master/arctic/chunkstore/chunkstore.py)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue actually is not a memory issue. If you read your errors, it seems that your library is having trouble accessing your data...

1st Error: Says your server has timed out. (`ServerSelectionTimeoutError`)

2nd Error: Trying to update MongoDB version.

3rd Error: Retries accessing your server, fails.(`ServerSelectionTimeoutError`)

etc. So essentially your problem lies in the Arctic package itself (see last error is a checksum error). You can also deduce this from the fact that `df_q.to_csv()` works, however it is very slow since it is not optimized like Artic. I would suggest trying to reinstall the Arctic package